# An element with a "root" ID already exists. magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:157

Tags: magento2, magento-community, magento2.3.2

I have been receiving this error for a while in the exception.log. It links to Framework/Data/Structure.php

```
 /**
 * Create new element
 *
 * @param string $elementId
 * @param array $data
 * @return void
 * @throws LocalizedException if an element with this id already exists
 */
public function createElement($elementId, array $data)
{
    if (isset($this->_elements[$elementId])) {
        throw new LocalizedException(
            new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('An element with a "%1" ID already exists.', [$elementId])
        );
    }
    $this->_elements[$elementId] = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $this->setAttribute($elementId, $key, $value);
    }
}
```

I have searched in the Database for "root" but nothing showed up. Can anyone help me please.

Thank you